# swift uitoolbar not showing all of the buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

In my code, I create a for loop which creates a uibarbuttonitem for all 17 items in my array like this.
my array is

```
let musicalnotes = ["C", "C♯", "D", "D♯", "E", "F", "F♯", "G", "G♯", "A", "A♯", "B", "E♭", "E","G♭", "A♭", "B♭"]


func createnotes(){

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   // toolBar.frame = CGRect(x: toolBar.frame.origin.x, y: toolBar.frame.origin.y, width: toolBar.frame.size.width, height: 900)
    var buttonarray = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    for a in musicalnotes {
        let a = UIBarButtonItem(title: a, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.addnotetonote(sender:)))

        buttonarray.append(a)
    }
    let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.revert))
    buttonarray.append(cancel)
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.items = buttonarray
```

My problem is the toolbar on an iPhone shows the buttons like so:

[iphone example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Km2.png)

On an iPhone, the buttons are not visible but functioning, but on an iPad it's normal.

Is it because there are too many buttons to fit on the toolbar or something else?

Comment: i've already tried size to fit as well.

Comment: There is a limit to the number of  Bar Buttons that you can adds. Apparently, the view containing the buttons is clipping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add toolBar into a UIScrollView.

```
scrollView.addSubview(toolBar)
```

And would recommend using auto layout

```
toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
toolBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out with your help. I'll copy the code in the main question in case anyone has trouble with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using the answer above. Here is the solved code.

```
 toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33 * 20, height: toolBar.frame.size.height)
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.frame = toolBar.frame;
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = toolBar.autoresizingMask;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.addSubview(toolBar)
        toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        toolBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        notes.inputAccessoryView = scrollView
        notes.reloadInputViews()
```